# Getting existing Assembly names dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, aspnetboilerplate

I'm student.

How you do get exist assemblies after build?

 I have a plugin based on ABP templates and want share that for other ABP users. 

 This plugin need a reference from AbpTemplate.Core to Plugin.Core nothing else. But problem is users AbpTemplate's have own project naming. 

 I'm try config Plugin.Core.csproj to getting that AbpTamplate.Core default assembly name.

Is it possible? If yes how you can do this? Thanks.

Comment: a csproj file is just xml

Comment: @Ctznkane525 that not possible in xml or I need to learn xml?

Comment: .net has xml reader classes built in...go ahead and open the csproj in notepad and youll see what i mean

Comment: @Ctznkane525 using xml reader after build is possible? That reference is for AbpTamplateModule.cs. That helped me to get assembly for embedded resources and application host.

Comment: Maybe try to better explain what you are exactly trying to accomplish. Your attempted way may just be going in the wrong direction and there are better ways to solve that